# Getting data from a column using python without using pyexcel or other libraries

Tags: python

I am attempting to analyse a large data set that I currently have stored in .csv format.I want to store data from the 3rd column into hours, minutes and seconds fields and then carry out some calculations.

[image: Data set to be analysed]

I do not usually work in python and most of the solutions I am able to find suggest using libraries such as pyexcel or astropy. However, the machine that I have been given to work on does not have these packages. I can not get permission to install any packages and have been told I have to work with what I have available.How would I carry out the task using only the python language and pylab?

Comment: Have you looked at the builtin [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: try use [vritualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), with which you can install any python packages without admin rights, unless internet access is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to read one line at a time using the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) [**`reader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and then yield the values you want. This makes the function a generator, which efficiently only reads and uses as much memory as it needs per line.

The value you want in the 4th column (column 3 counting from zero), is space delimited values, which you can split and map to floats (or something more complex if you wish):

```
>>> hms = '03 26 02.785'
>>> hms.split()
['03', '26', '02.785']

>>> map(float, _)
[3.0, 26.0, 2.785]
```

Altogether:

```
import csv

def hours_minutes_seconds(filelike):
    for line in csv.reader(filelike):
        RAJ2000 = line[3]
        yield map(float, RAJ2000.split())
```

[**`csv.reader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) expects a file-like object (or anything iterable that returns strings), so we can test it using [**`StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

Usage:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> contents = StringIO.StringIO("""1,1,C001,03 26 02.785
... 2,2,C002,03 26 04.152""")

>>> for hms in hours_minutes_seconds(contents):
...     print hms
[3.0, 26.0, 2.785]
[3.0, 26.0, 4.152]
```